# ¿Cómo ordenar ventas por mes en Linq?

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql

Estoy utilizando C# con windows forms y tengo mapeada en Entity-Framework la siguiente tabla:

```
         Ventas

    ID_Venta = smallint
    Fecha = date
    Cant_Ventas = tinyint
    Tot_Tarjeta = smallmoney
    Tot_Venta = smallmoney
```

En WindowsForms ingreso la venta por dia. Para ser mas claro, cuando cierro la caja almaceno la cantidad de ventas, el total vendido con tarjeta, el total "general" y fecha.

Quedando la tabla algo como esto:

```
    ID_Venta     Fecha     Cant_Ventas   Tot_Tarjeta  Tot_Venta
    1          2019-01-1      20            400          1000
    2          2019-01-2      15            200          1500  
    3          2019-01-3      25            300          1430
```

Lo que quiero hacer es agrupar las ventas (No me interesa mostrar las ventas hechas con tarjeta) hechas por mes usando LinQ y después mostrarlo en un DataGridView. Me gustaría obtener algo como esto:

```
    Mes   Total
    1     25000
    2     47050
    3     59600
```

EN SQL logre hacerlo mediante el siguiente código:

```
    select Month(Fecha) as Mes, SUM(Tot_Venta) as Total
    from Ventas
    group by Month(Fecha)
    order by Mes
```

¿Cómo puedo hacer esto con LinQ? Por mas que busqué, no encontré la solución.

Espero haber sido lo más claro posible. Gracias por tomarse el tiempo de leer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es la versión Linq de tu SQL:

```
ventas
    .GroupBy(venta => venta.Fecha.Month)
    .Select(grupo => new { mes = grupo.Key, total = grupo.Sum(venta => venta.Total) })
    .OrderBy(result => result.mes);
```

No obstante, ten cuidado porque no estás teniendo en cuenta el año, estás agrupando los meses iguales de años distintos. Para tener en cuenta el año también podrías hacer algo como esto:

```
ventas
    .GroupBy(venta => new { mes = venta.Fecha.Month, año = venta.Fecha.Year })
    .Select(grupo => new { fecha = grupo.Key, total = grupo.Sum(venta => venta.Total) })
    .OrderBy(result => result.fecha.año)
    .ThenBy(result => result.fecha.mes);
```

Ahora tu resultado en vez de tener un campo "mes" numérico tiene un campo "fecha" que es un objeto con mes y año.

Comment: Serías por favor tan amable de explicarme la lógica de pensamiento para realizar eso? O de sugerirme alguna documentación? Todavía estoy verde en Linq, pero con muchas ganas de entenderlo. Creo que estas usando Lambda, pero no sé que función tiene el "punto" delante de cada comienzo de línea.

Comment: Al realizar la consulta que me indicaste recibo el siguiente error: El cuerpo de una consulta debe terminar con una claúsula select o group. No sé cómo darle el formato adecuado para enviarte el bloque de código que tengo hecho para la consulta en los comentarios.